# JMonkeyEngine FullScreen Script

Tags: fullscreen

I'm pretty new to Java scripting I was wondering if any of you could tell me what's wrong with these lines:

```
GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnviroment.
     getLocalGraphicEnviroment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
settings.setResolution(modes[0].getWidth(), modes][0].getHeight());
settings.setFrequency(mdoe{[0].getFrequencyRate());
settings.setDepthBits(modes[0].getBitDepth());
settings.setFullscreen(device.isFullScreenSupported());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure we could debate the meaning of the word 'script', but that is Java, not a Java script (and certainly not javascript)...

You have several problems with extra punctuation, missing variable declarations, and misspelled method names.  The code you want can be found on the jME3 [website](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3%3aintermediate%3aappsettings):

```
public void toggleToFullscreen() {
  GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
  DisplayMode[] modes = device.getDisplayModes();
  int i=0; // note: there are usually several, let's pick the first
  settings.setResolution(modes[i].getWidth(),modes[i].getHeight());
  settings.setFrequency(modes[i].getRefreshRate());
  settings.setBitsPerPixel(modes[i].getBitDepth());
  settings.setFullscreen(device.isFullScreenSupported());
  app.setSettings(settings);
  app.restart(); // restart the context to apply changes
}
```